# Where PostGIS gets its spatial_ref_sys table data

Tags: postgis

After updating PostGIS  versions we noticed there were thousands of extra projections added that did not exist previously. I was wondering where PostGIS gets its list of projections, and how is it decided which projections get added to the list?

Comment: It seems to me that the srs list is updated more or less manually in https://github.com/postgis/postgis/commits/master/spatial_ref_sys.sql. And obviously the problems with updating are resolved if you got that many new entries https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/5024.